# Z-index with font awesome icons is not working

Tags: html, css, z-index, font-awesome

I am using the font awesome icon to display on the button so that it appears as clicked but it is not visible completely.

I have used `z-index` for that but it doesn't work

**If I use `z-index: 0` or a higher value**

[image: Z-index as 0 or above]

**If i use a `z-index` value below 0**

[image: Z-index below 0]

```js
function onClick(ele) {
  document.getElementById('status1').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
.sta_tus {
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #005a84;
  background-color: #d5e2ed;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.fa-check-circle {
  right: 37px;
  position: relative;
  color: #00a2db;
  bottom: 33px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md sta_tus" onClick="onClick(this)">Just an Idea</button>
  <span id="status1" class="fa-stack fa-lg ">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle" ></i>
              </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions on this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us the function onClick? I didn't see it in your code

Comment: Hi, Actually when i click on the button the tick mark should be visible,but it's not working here so i made the tick mark visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `background-color: #fff;` on `.fa-check-circle` - it seems that the checkmark is transparent, which lets the border of the rectangle come trough underneath it.